# Time difference for date time columns

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table which will have the information about usage by user.Out of them 3 MySQL columns are **Module, Time1, Time2**.
I want to fetch time difference between Time1 & Time2
i.e Time difference between Module = started & 'Time1' and  Module = end & 'Time2' and also i want to consider only started and end combination. rest can be ignored.

As shown in screenshot, Thanks.

I have also created same data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1361c5 , Please use it.

[image]

Comment: You are asking for a complex query and you haven't done very much other than to dump an image link.  Please edit your question and include the data as text along with any query you have tried.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Please find updated question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query

```
SELECT
  q1.time1,
  q2.time2,
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(q2.time2)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(q1.time1) seconds
FROM
  (
    SELECT *,@i1:=IFNULL(@i1,0)+1 num
    FROM LogData
    ORDER BY time1
  ) q1
JOIN
  (
    SELECT *,@i2:=IFNULL(@i2,0)+1 num
    FROM LogData
    ORDER BY time1
  ) q2
ON q2.num=q1.num+1 AND q1.status='started' AND q2.status='end'
```

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fbbd89/7